# In Qt, how do I make a dialog un-resizeable, yet automatically adjusting its size to the contents?

Tags: c++, qt, size, qdialog

I have an instance of QDialog, populated by widgets using code generated by uic. The dialog contains a few labels laid out vertically, and I am popping the dialog from time to time to show some text in these labels. The text can be multi-line and its length is not pre-determined. I set the vertical size policy to fixed, so the user can't drag it (doesn't make sense), but I also want the dialog to change its size before being shown to accomodate for the current size of the labels.

To this end, I was calling QWidget::adjustSize() on the QDialog before displaying it, but it doesn't work as expected. When the dialog is shown, it seems to retain the (wrong) size from the previous displaying, but when I click the mouse in the (disabled) vertical resize mode, the dialog suddenly "snaps" to the (correct) adjusted size.

Is there any way to make my dialog appear correctly?

**EDIT:** I tied rubenvb's advice, and ended up with this:

```
QSizePolicy free(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);
QSizePolicy fixed(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
dialog->setSizePolicy(free);
dialog->adjustSize();
dialog->setSizePolicy(fixed);
dialog->show();
```

Unfortunately, that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Try to update the dialog after adjusting its size to force the widget to redraw itself

Comment: Do you mean with QObject::update()?

Comment: I mean updateGeometry : http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#updateGeometry

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer you're hoping for, and it may not apply to what you're trying to do, however, the only way that I was able to adjust the dimensions of a QWidget at run-time was by handling the object's resizeEvent(..) method. This allowed me to calc the size of items based upon the font being used, number of lines, available space, etc., and then adjust their size accordingly before passing the 'event' on to the base resizeEvent(..) method.

My approach used a single QWidget container within a window, below a header, above a footer status area, and to the right of a column of menu buttons. The widget container, inside the resizeEvent() call, would look at the objects it was going to display, calculate the font heights being used, and then resize some items according to their dimensions (because of how the style sheet selected fonts and colors, etc) and then adjust the sub-widget dimensions before allowing the container widget to get the resizeEvent() message.

So I wasn't so interested in setting a window size, but I think the container QWidget might work the same way? I was more interested in setting the dimensions to some asthetically pleasing size, depending upon the dimensions of the display.

Hope you find that helpful.

Comment: Well, if it turns out to be necessary, I suppose I'll have to go through this too, but I'd rather not. :) adjustSize() works fine for me, it's just that it seems I need to somehow force some kind of update before showing the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Do everything in the right order:

1. Dialog is not shown. Dialog is resizeable.
2. Calculate new size, set new size.
3. Set dialog to not-resizeable.
4. Show Dialog.
5. Hide dialog, go to step one.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work; see edit. Seemed like a great idea though. :(

Comment: What part doesn't work? Are you sure you're getting the correct size with things like sizeHint and friends?

Comment: The part where everything happens just the way it did before? I didn't bother with sizeHint, I figured the value from Designer would be fine.

Comment: @neuviemeporte: it's very important you know what size it's getting, because `adjustSize` uses "`sizeHint` and friends": http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#adjustSize Try a manual size to see if my way actually works, and your problem is surely based on something going wrong (not your fault per se) in `sizeHint`.